Copilot/vscode error: solution 0 returned. finish reason: stop
I'm searching since a bit of time but can't find a solution, when i use copilot it doesn't want to complete or any other thing, when i check the output on Visual Studio Code I have this:
2024-04-25 18:31:45.714 [info] [streamChoices] solution 0 returned. finish reason: [stop]
2024-04-25 18:31:45.717 [info] [streamChoices] request done: headerRequestId: [5b002aad-85e2-4311-8ed3-ea39731ca800] model deployment ID: [y24ab577359d6]
2024-04-25 18:31:46.817 [info] [fetchCompletions] request.response: [https://copilot-proxy.githubusercontent.com/v1/engines/copilot-codex/completions] took 133 ms

Copilot version is v1.182.0 and vscode version is 1.88.1

has been raised before in various appropriate channels and so far no answer from MS. https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/34845, https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/53018, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Copilot-stops-working-when-requesting-co/10607240?space=41&sort=newest
